# What are .serverauth.##### files in my home directory?

Tags: ssh, files, x11, home

The files are `.serverauth.#####` where `#####` is a 5-digit number.
I have a handful of these files in my home directory with a broad range of creation dates spanning a couple of years.

What are these files from?  Is it safe to delete them?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can remove all of them except the newest one. They are created by the `startx` script. If X does not shut down gracefully, that files is not removed and stays forever (see that [bug](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xinit/+bug/35758)).

You can change the line in the `/usr/bin/startx` file, to a more handy way:

Search for `xserverauthfile=` in the script and replace the line with:

```
xserverauthfile=$XAUTHORITY
```

Comment: Could you explain what else this fix changes? If I understand correctly, after the change, there will be single auth file `~/.Xauthority`. Why default `startx` script prefers to create uniquely named auth files to begin with?

Answer (score 10):

Each time you start an X windows session, that file gets created and it is deleted when X session exits normally. If startx exits ungracefully - for instance, if the shutdown sequence sends it a kill signal (the script doesn't catch signals) - the file will never be removed. It is safe to remove these files.
There are probable solutions but I've never tested for side effects. Change following line in your `startx` command (`/usr/bin/startx`):

```
xserverauthfile=$HOME/.serverauth.$$
```

to

```
xserverauthfile=$XAUTHORITY
```